# Parameter returnUrl is null when passed from Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Based on what I have seen here in stackoverflow, I have an `Html.BeginForm` as so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Account", new {returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

    <br/>

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
}
```

On debug mode, I get a null value on my returnUrl in my Controller but the model is filled. 
[image]

This is my Web.config

```
<system.web>
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Index" defaultUrl="~/Home/Default" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyProvider" type="EventCalendar.MyRoleProvider.SiteRole"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Have you inspect `Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]` value? If no request coming from other action which requires authorized user, by default it contains null value.

Comment: You don't need extra parameter in the Action method you can retrieve extra query string parameters using Request.QueryStrings["returnUrl"] in the Action method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, in the Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] do I have to put in the actual url say, Request.QueryString["~/Home/Default"]?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya : What you're saying is I do mot need to pass the returnUrl  parameter because I can get it in the action itself? Like so: In the controller - var url = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"] ..... return Redirect(url);

Comment: Nope. `Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]` contains URL where the request comes from by calling "ReturnUrl" as its key, hence don't use relative path as key. As an alternative you can get the query string request in GET action method, and store it in a hidden field of user login form.

Comment: Yes.. correct... since you are setting querystring values in BeginForm, it will appended in the URL. So in the POST action, you just need to do Request.QueryStrings["returnUrl"] to get that value.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that as soon as I get tomy PC.

Comment: If you want to retrieve query string, put in GET method where the request retrieved, e.g. `ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]` and set in the form: `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Account", new { returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post))`.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense!

Comment: Hmmm.. I still get null value when I use the ViewBag.ReturnUrl and even when I do this => var x = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]; <= in my controller, I still get x = null. Please see the updated code and Image.

Comment: Have you using Forms Authentication in web.config file? If it's true, put `[Authorize]` on top of the controller class & `[AllowAnonymous]` at `Index` methods. But if it's no, you should use URL from `Request.UrlReferrer` like this: `Server.UrlEncode(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery)`.

Comment: Yes I am using forms authentication in the Web.config. It's not in the above code but I placed Authorized attribute on the top of my "Default" method in the "Home" controller.

Comment: Try to place both attributes, I think `AuthorizeAttribute` will redirect to login page defined in `loginUrl` attribute inside web.config (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx). The `ReturnUrl` part exists in query string if it comes from action method which has `[Authorize]` attribute.